# Google Apps Script setvalue not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Apps Script to create a Google Sheet populated with information from my emails. In column F, I want to create the same formula in all of the rows that will split the delimited values in Column E.

```
var LastColumn = sheets[1].getLastColumn();
sheets[1].insertColumnAfter(LastColumn);
var LastRow = sheets[1].getLastRow();
for (var a = 1; a < LastRow; a++){
    var cell = sheets[1].getRange('F'+a);
    var place = "=SPLIT(E"+a+",',')";
    cell.setValue(place);
};
```

While testing, the dynamic range never writes the set value formula. I've changed the formula to a hard-coded value, but it still does not write to the sheet.

Any thoughts?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setFormula:

```
function myTest() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var LastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(LastColumn);
  var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var a = 1; a < LastRow; a++){
    var cell = sheet.getRange('F'+a);
    var place = '=SPLIT(E'+a+', ",")';
    cell.setFormula(place);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. When I navigate to the cell on the sheet, it's empty, the formula is not populating in cell. When I switch it to setValue, the value does not appear.

Comment: You might want to carefully check your syntax. I built this in a sheet and it worked great.

Comment: Thanks, put it as a new function and it works. Not sure why it doesn't work nested.